# pandas iterrows changes ints into floats

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to iterate over the rows of a DataFrame that contains some int64s and some floats. `iterrows()` seems to be turning my ints into floats, which breaks everything I want to do downstream:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[10000000000000001, 1.5], [10000000000000002, 2.5]], columns=['id', 'prc'])
>>> [id for id in df.id]
[10000000000000001, 10000000000000002]
>>> [r['id'] for (idx,r) in df.iterrows()]
[10000000000000000.0, 10000000000000002.0]
```

Iterating directly over `df.id` is fine. But through `iterrows()`, I get different values. Is there a way to iterate over the rows in such a way that I can still index by column name *and* get all the correct values?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)'s the relevant part of the docs:

> Because `iterrows` returns a Series for each row, **it does not preserve dtypes across the rows** (dtypes are preserved across columns for DataFrames) [...] To **preserve** dtypes while iterating over the rows, it is better to use `itertuples()` which returns namedtuples of the values and which is generally faster as `iterrows`.

Example for your data:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[10000000000000001, 1.5], [10000000000000002, 2.5]], columns=['id', 'prc'])
>>> [t[1] for t in df.itertuples()]
[10000000000000001, 10000000000000002]
```

Answer (score 3):

If possible you're better off avoiding iteration. Check if you can vectorize your work first.

If vectorization is impossible, you probably want `DataFrame.itertuples`. That will return an iterable of (named)tuples where the first element is the index label.

```
In [2]: list(df.itertuples())
Out[2]:
[Pandas(Index=0, id=10000000000000001, prc=1.5),
 Pandas(Index=1, id=10000000000000002, prc=2.5)]
```

`iterrows` returns a Series for each row. Since series  are backed by numpy arrays, whose elements must all share a single type, your ints were cast as floats.